# Do active stone blocks count as a floor for a house?

Tags: terraria

I'd like to build one of my NPCs' houses with a retractable floor so that I can repeatedly drop them
into... things. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the Housing Query?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I started a new map and don't have any blocks to test with yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that houses can be built with retractable floors. My NPCs need to prepare for some adventure. Any furniture will need to be on a platform above the floor or it will have to be replaced every time the floor is activated.

Comment: This makes me want to re-install.

Comment: Poor NPCs. I prefer building traps around the house. Without lava moats around my house I just don't feel safe any more at night in the hard mode..